# Load Remote Data Source into Magento Admin Products Grid

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to essentially create a split screen view, one grid of a remote repository full of products, and another alongside it showing the local repository in a grid.

I think that essentially sums it up, I'll give partial credit if you can tell me how to simply incorporate the remote source into the grid... I think I could handle it from there even.  Please be thoughtful, I don't really want to hear how to configure my resources in the config.xml, I already can do that with a remote database, i just can't get the objects/collections to load from it.

Thanks guys.

Comment: well, currently i'm attempting to create a model based on catalog_product_flat_1 in the remote database, it's creating the model fine but it isn't loading any data.  I've tried a few other things... if all else fails i will probably just create generic varien_objects and pull the data manually into them and add them to a generic collection... i *know* that will work as inelegant as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK-- So for those of us who've tried something like this, the first thing you realize is that when you want more than one database as a source in your module... you actually need *2* modules to do so (someone chime in and correct me if i'm wrong).

Step 1: Create a "dummy" module to connect with your remote database.  This module should pretty much just contain etc/ and Model/ -- there's no real need for anything else.  My config.xml looks as follows:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mage_RepoDummy>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mage_RepoDummy>
</modules>

<global>
    <resources>
        <repodummy_write>
            <connection>
                <use>repodummy_database</use>
            </connection>
        </repodummy_write>
        <repodummy_read>
            <connection>
                <use>repodummy_database</use>
            </connection>
        </repodummy_read>
        <repodummy_setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </repodummy_setup>
        <repodummy_database>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[brandrepo]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[*******]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[brandrepo]]></dbname>
                <model>mysql4</model>
                <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>           
        </repodummy_database>                 
    </resources>      
     <models>
        <repodummy>
            <class>Mage_RepoDummy_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>repodummy_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </repodummy>
        <repodummy_mysql4>
            <class>Mage_RepoDummy_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <product>
                    <table>catalog_product_entity</table>
                </product>
            </entities>
        </repodummy_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>

<adminhtml>  
</adminhtml>
```

Now you'll need the following model and resource files:

```
/Model/Product.php
/Model/Mysql4/Product.php
/Model/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php
```

In Product.php:

```
class Mage_RepoDummy_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('repodummy/product', 'entity_id'); 
    }
}
```

In Mysql4/Product.php

```
class Mage_RepoDummy_Model_Mysql4_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
             ->setConnection('repodummy_read', 'repodummy_write');
        $this->_productWebsiteTable  = $this->getTable('catalog/product_website');
        $this->_productCategoryTable = $this->getTable('catalog/category_product');
    }
}
```

And In Mysql4/Product/Collection.php

```
class Mage_RepoDummy_Model_Mysql4_Product_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract {

    protected function _construct()
    {
            $this->_init('repodummy/product');
    }
}
```

Just barebones type stuff, like you'd do for any basic model in Magento.  Now from another module, that's rigged to any other database, probably/possibly your local instance, you can access this remote data store by invoking your dummy object, if you wanted to test this just do something simple like:

```
    $test = Mage::getModel('repodummy/product')->load(10367);

    die("::".$test->getSku()."::");
```

...and this model should function just like your typical product model for the most part, except you're using a remote database, happy coding!

Comment: I want to follow up and say, advanced use of the collection in this case isn't possible with just what I've given here.  If you say copied the Product Grid control and just plugged in this new model, all other things being equal it would not work... but the rest of that answer is a little much for the space here-- if you're smart you should be able to get it one way or another.

Comment: Going to upvote for visibility, as I am trying to do similar and this question was difficult to find. I assume there are loads of devs out there working on migrations like I am and older API methods simply aren't practical - direct use of Magento models is so much faster when working with a ton of remote data.

Comment: Do you have a way to add a table prefix for the remote table?